# JMS Queue w/o response

Tags: maven, jms, websphere, java-ee-8

I am setting up a JMS Queue and was having trouble with the service. I cannot find any examples, but also no definite no's, on sending a JMS queue and no response. I have to send an object from one module to another for an update, no response needed. Can JMS handle this or is a response necessary? After implementing mine, the other JMS service is getting an EJB not found error on deployment, haven't touched it, and was wondering if this is a common, or stupid mistake, that somebody could point me to.

Set up the server xml, ejb-jar, Queue directories and such. When I deploy the other EJB gives a non existent error and will not deploy the module.

This is an enterprise env. and the code is spread out through many different directories and classes.

Just need to make the message send... If you down vote, call me stupid but attach a quick reference guide I'll take it. Only have 2 days to get this working.

Comment: Sending messages without response is most common JMS scenario, so you are on the right track. You would need to add your piece of code and detailed exception what is not working for you, for community to give you some hints. Your receiving side should be MDB, maybe it is misconfigured and thats why you have exception.

Comment: What do you mean by a "response"? Are you talking about an actual JMS message which will act as a response? Are you talking about a confirmation from the broker that it actually received the message from the client (this is typically called a "blocking" send and is usually done by default for persistent messages)?

Comment: the basic JMS protocol is 'fire-and-forget', so no response needed. Once you have sent the message to the queue, do you have other means to see if that succeeded ? Is this WebLogic you are talking about ?

Comment: I am not getting any errors at all. None on the websphere log or on my local output in intelliJ. I have it set up w/a EE application using maven and war files so modules are not dependencies but are on the same server. When the application sends the message, it acts as if it was sent successfully, nothing logged at all, but nothing happnes after that. Not sure how to figure out where the disconnect is since there is nothing to trace. How would I debug this?

Comment: I have solved this issue... I had my ibm-ejb file under the business package, since that is where the consumer was, but it needed to be in the web module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set up my ejb file under the business package since that is where my consumer was, this configuration needed to be in the web module.